# Process va_args in c++

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I have a function `A(...)` and `B(...)`. Now I have to call `B` inside `A`, any methods to pass that `...` from `A` into `B`? Pseudocode:

```
void A(...)
{
   // Some operators
   B(...); // Instead of ... I need to pass A's args
}
```

p.s. I know this could be done using macros but what about functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't forward va_args. You can only forward va_list.

```
void vB(int first, va_list ap)
{
   // do stuff with ap.
}

void B(int first, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   va_start(ap, first);
   vB(first, ap);
   va_end(ap);
}

void A(int something_else, int first, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   va_start(ap, first);
   vB(first, ap);       // <-- call vB instead of B.
   va_end(ap);
}
```

(This is also why functions like `vprintf` exists.)

---

If you are using C++11, you could do this with variadic templates with perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename... T>
void A(T&&... args)
{
    B(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't take a `va-list` and pass it to a function accepting a variable argument list. There is no syntax allowing you to expand the va_args structure back into parameters.

You can pass it as a `va_list` in a single parameter, so one solution would be to define the function that does the work as taking a `va_list`. Then you can define another function wrapping it taking an argument list which can then pass a `va_list` to the core function and pass the return value back. You see this kind of pattern in the C standard library with `printf()` and `vprintf()` and similar pairings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to slightly change the signature of your methods. I assume you want to do something like this:

```
void B(int numParams, va_list parameters)
{
    // Your code here. Example:
    for (int i=0; i<numParams; i++)
    {
        // Do something using va_arg to retrieve your parameters
    }
}

void A(int numParams, ...)
{
    va_list parameters;
    va_start(parameters, numParams);
    B(numParams, parameters);
    va_end(parameters);
}
```